# Check boxes in JSF 2 checked

Tags: java, jsf-2

I have a JSF template (xhtml) and I have some checkboxes. But then the page loads I need check boxes to be checked.
Here is my code:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox
                  layout="pageDirection"
                  required="true"
                  value="#{myBean.values}">
<f:selectItem itemValue="v1" itemLabel="l1"/>
<f:selectItem itemValue="v2" itemLabel="l2"/>
<f:selectItem itemValue="v3" itemLabel="l3"/>
<f:selectItem itemValue="v4" itemLabel="l4"/>
<f:selectItem itemValue="v5" itemLabel="l5"/>
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

How can I make the checkboxes to be selected when page is loaded? I can find any tags in JSF that specifies checkbox to be checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `#{myBean.values}` holds the selected values (the checked checkboxes in this case). So you must make sure that `myBean.values` contains the `itemValue` items of the `selectItem`s you want to see checked. For example:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{myBean.values}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="v1" itemLabel="l1"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="v2" itemLabel="l2"/>
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

In the above, populate `myBean.values` with `"v1"` and `"v2"` to show them as checked.